# Weird negative length array created into Class.getDeclaredFields that makes JVM to throw a NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: java, scala, jvm

I Use Java 15 openjdk and tried on Java 14

- Include details about your goal
  I'm making a RMI system in order to make instances of any object synchronisable between computers and make multiple engines works on the same object. With my system, when i want to synchronise an object, i generate a class that will extends the object class and then override every methods of the class in order to control if the method call must be delegated to the object or to perform a RMI request instead.
  The class generation is divided in two part :

1. I generate the source code in which every non-final methods are overriden in order to add my delegating system. the code is generated in scala language, and this class yet does not extends from the class of the object to synchronise because scala don't let me override some methods, even if they are not final (it's a thing with scala's setters and getters), then i compile the code using the Scala Compiler.
2. I use javassist to modify the generated class and make it extends the expected class + i add some methods and modify anonfun methods in order to perform super calls.

- What is happening when i see the exception ?
  I have a module `Server` and a module `Client`, they both run the same code except that they have different implementation of the `Engine` module, which is where i define all features of my framework, my RMI system is a feature of the framework for example, and for this RMI system, absolutely no code is runned into the implementations modules.
  In the Engine module, I've made a `player` command in my program that creates a synchronised list (of type scala.collections.mutable.ListBuffer), thus, with this command i can add some player objects to the list. for example, if i add a player to the list, it will be added in the local list of the program that executes the command, and a RMI request will be done to the other computers that hosts the list in order to make them add the same object in their list.
  Now, if i enter something like `player add id=7 name=testPlayer x=78 y=23`, it will start to get completely weird :
  First of all, this exception occurs only when the server program handles the RMI request, which is completely nonsensical because as i said, nothing is run in the implementation.
  For example, if i enter the command on the server, the player will be added in it's local list, and a RMI request for the add method will be sent from the server to the client, but on the client, as it will handle the request, will not crash at all (i can spam the command, nothing breaks). So, if the server handles the RMI request, it throws me this error :

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -531627648
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.copyFields(Class.java:3538)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2341)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.ClassDescription.listAllSerialFields$1(ClassDescription.scala:45)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.ClassDescription.listSerializableFields(ClassDescription.scala:52)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.ClassDescription.<init>(ClassDescription.scala:23)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.DefaultClassProfile.<init>(DefaultClassProfile.scala:23)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.DefaultSerialContext.$anonfun$getClassProfile$1(DefaultSerialContext.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:454)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.DefaultSerialContext.getClassProfile(DefaultSerialContext.scala:61)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.DefaultNodeFinder.getClassProfile(DefaultNodeFinder.scala:49)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.DefaultNodeFinder.getSerialNodeForType(DefaultNodeFinder.scala:36)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.DefaultNodeFinder.getSerialNodeForRef(DefaultNodeFinder.scala:44)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.DefaultNodeFinder.$anonfun$listNodes$1(DefaultNodeFinder.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:246)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.DefaultNodeFinder.listNodes(DefaultNodeFinder.scala:53)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.nodes.ObjectNode$ObjectSerialNode.serialize(ObjectNode.scala:58)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.nodes.ArrayNode$ArraySerialNode.serializeItem$1(ArrayNode.scala:84)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.nodes.ArrayNode$ArraySerialNode.$anonfun$serialize$1(ArrayNode.scala:68)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.nodes.ArrayNode$ArraySerialNode.$anonfun$serialize$1$adapted(ArrayNode.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.ArrayOps$.foreach$extension(ArrayOps.scala:1323)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.nodes.ArrayNode$ArraySerialNode.serialize(ArrayNode.scala:67)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.LengthSign$.$anonfun$of$2(LengthSign.scala:62)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.LengthSign$.$anonfun$of$2$adapted(LengthSign.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.LengthSign$.of(LengthSign.scala:54)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.nodes.ObjectNode$ObjectSerialNode.serialize(ObjectNode.scala:63)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.nodes.ArrayNode$ArraySerialNode.serializeItem$1(ArrayNode.scala:84)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.nodes.ArrayNode$ArraySerialNode.$anonfun$serialize$1(ArrayNode.scala:68)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.nodes.ArrayNode$ArraySerialNode.$anonfun$serialize$1$adapted(ArrayNode.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.ArrayOps$.foreach$extension(ArrayOps.scala:1323)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.tree.nodes.ArrayNode$ArraySerialNode.serialize(ArrayNode.scala:67)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.scala:34)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.SimpleTransferInfo.makeSerial(SimpleTransferInfo.scala:38)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.LazyPacketSerializationResult.bytes$lzycompute(LazyPacketSerializationResult.scala:27)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.LazyPacketSerializationResult.bytes(LazyPacketSerializationResult.scala:27)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.LazyPacketSerializationResult.writableBytes$lzycompute(LazyPacketSerializationResult.scala:30)
    at fr.linkit.engine.connection.packet.serialization.LazyPacketSerializationResult.writableBytes(LazyPacketSerializationResult.scala:29)
    at fr.linkit.server.connection.ExternalConnectionSession.send(ExternalConnectionSession.scala:53)
    at fr.linkit.server.connection.ServerExternalConnection.$anonfun$sendPacket$1(ServerExternalConnection.scala:100)
    at fr.linkit.engine.local.concurrency.pool.BusyWorkerPool.$anonfun$runLater$1(BusyWorkerPool.scala:351)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:210)
    at fr.linkit.engine.local.concurrency.pool.BusyWorkerPool.$anonfun$runLaterControl$1(BusyWorkerPool.scala:122)
    at fr.linkit.engine.local.concurrency.SimpleAsyncTask.runTask(SimpleAsyncTask.scala:75)
    at fr.linkit.engine.local.concurrency.pool.BusyWorkerThread.runTask(BusyWorkerThread.scala:67)
    at fr.linkit.engine.local.concurrency.pool.BusyWorkerPool.$anonfun$runLaterControl$2(BusyWorkerPool.scala:132)
```

The exception occurs during the serialization of the response packet, (as we are performing a Remote Method Invocation, we have to send the return value of the method). In this case, the `add` method returns the instance of the list, so the packet will contains the instance of the list as a result value (sounds useless but i have to deal with this kind of situations). When the list gets serialized, it crashes here :

```scala
def listAllSerialFields(cl: Class[_]): Seq[Field] = {
            if (cl == null)
                return Seq.empty
            val fields = cl.getDeclaredFields //Line 45, Here, the cl value is the generated class
            fields
                    .filterNot(p => Modifier.isTransient(p.getModifiers) || Modifier.isStatic(p.getModifiers))
                    .tapEach(_.setAccessible(true))
                    .toList ++ listAllSerialFields(cl.getSuperclass)
        }
```

Then, further in the method it crashes here :

```java
private static Field[] copyFields(Field[] arg) {
        Field[] out = new Field[arg.length]; //arg.length is -500 millions !
        ReflectionFactory fact = getReflectionFactory();
        for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
            out[i] = fact.copyField(arg[i]);
        }
        return out;
    }
```

I suspect that it's the reflection data that causes that because, when i used the debugger to follow the thread execution, the jvm crashed when the debugger saw the referent field of the SoftReference<ReflectionData> Class.reflectionData field. But i repeat, on the client it does not crash, and my debugger can inspect the reflection data successfully.

**EDIT -**
If i call getDeclaredFields directly once the class get loaded (here for example):

```scala
var loader = puppetClass.getClassLoader
                if (loader == null)
                    loader = getClass.getClassLoader //Use the Application's classloader

                val classLoader = new GeneratedClassLoader(folderPath, loader, Seq(classOf[LinkitApplication].getClassLoader))
                val clazz = Class.forName(wrapperClassName, false, classLoader).asInstanceOf[Class[_ <: PuppetWrapper[AnyRef]]]
                println(s"CREATED CLASS ${clazz} IN THREAD = " + Thread.currentThread())
                clazz.getDeclaredFields //Invoking a method in order to make the class load its reflectionData (causes fatal error if not made directly)
                ClassMappings.putClass(clazz)
                clazz
```

It will never crash or throw me the an exception, however, it still weird that i have to do that because only the server would *oftenly* crash, and when it crashes, it can does it in the exact same thread that have loaded the class...

Comment: Try running the JVM with `-Xint -Xverify:all`

Comment: It's weird, i'm on another (much much slower computer) and it did not throw an NegativeArraySizeException at first time, so i decided to spam the `player` command and the jvm crashed, even if i didnt use any debugger https://hastebin.com/agebefigaq.yaml here are the logs

Comment: for the JVM arguments, i've added them but i didn't got any print in the console (maybe they are in the log) @apangin

Comment: Seems like Java Heap corruption. Does your code use `sun.misc.Unsafe` somewhere?

Comment: yep, i use it in order to instanciate the synchronised object and in my serialization system to paste set values into fields

Comment: That's exactly why `Unsafe` is called unsafe. There is a high chance the bug is in that code.

Comment: so how can i fix that ? it does not crash when i use Unsafe... and i can't stop using it + i'm not using Unsafe to modify the java.lang.Class

Comment: Yeah, that's the most wonderful property of Unsafe: if there is a bug in unsafe code, noone knows what happens. A JVM may crash immediately, or after a few days of working. And it's not even the worst thing. The real problems begin when some business data is corrupted *silently*.

Comment: mhh i see, but what can i do ? i always used it in my project, and now that i use it on object of a generated class, it makes that ? its sounds weird because my generated classes are not complicated at all, maybe it's javassist that creates weird bytecode but if it's the bytecode, i would get a VerifyError when i load the class...

Comment: What could create corrupted data ?, is there a way to replace Unsafe ? (i can't use reflection because i won't be able to set final fields values and i need to allocate an instance, i can't call any constructor

Comment: Can provide more details regarding your use of Unsafe? Can you paste all of the relevant code or link to your project? (assuming its public)

Comment: i've made an edit

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to your original question, but re-iterates what was said in the comments. What you're doing is "unsafe", and the behavior is undefined. The fact that the workaround is working at all is somewhat incidental and cannot be relied upon. Maybe it works now, but in a future Java version it might fail.

The `Unsafe` class is going away once safe replacements exist for all of its useful capabilities. This will likely occur after the completion of the Panama project, which provides access to native memory. The `VarHandle` class is the replacement for direct field access, but it doesn't permit modifying final fields, and it likely never will. Such a backdoor prevents certain optimizations, and new Java features like "records" and "hidden classes" trust that final fields are really final. This behavior might apply to all classes at some point.

There's no planned safe alternative for allocating classes without a constructor, and so that's a problem too. The built-in Java serialization mechanism will have to continue using a backdoor until it's rewritten to use a different technique.

The safe technique is to generate a hidden constructor which performs deserialization and sets the final fields. It might also need dummy parameters to avoid conflicts with any other constructors. The constructor is added with an instrumentation agent which modifies serializable classes as they're loaded.

Ideally the hidden constructor should be private, but then accessing it becomes tricky. The agent should also define (or augment) a static class intializer which looks up the `MethodHandle` for the hidden constructor and passes it to some serialization framework layer. The private constructor will still be visible by any code which calls `getDeclaredConstructors`, but that's a relatively minor problem.

As for serializing the fields out in the first place, a `VarHandle` for each field can be passed along from the static initializer, or a private method is added which does the serialization. I think that the private method approach is better, and it just needs one `MethodHandle` for accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for ones who tried to help me, and thanks to boneil for his answer because he made me become aware that Unsafe wasn't a great solution, but i still have to deal with it. However, i decided to answer because i just made a "discovery" with the Unsafe.allocateInstance method : When Unsafe allocates an instance, every fields of the objects are null but still neverless non detected as null by the JVM. I just had a case where i didn't knew why i got an exception in the init method of one of my allocated instances, i first started to think that it was called twice, but it turned out that i could'nt even debug the method execution with a breakpoint because it was making my JVM crash as soon as the debugger stops in the instance's method. Thus, as i could not use the debugger, i decided to use the plain old nooby printf statement, but still unable to debug as i got a NPE here :

```java
(in java.lang.String.java)
    public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString(); //obj is null.
    }
```

as you can see,  the obj was null as it threw a NPE, but it still has been considerated as a normal instance. Therefore, by seeing this, i decided to use reflection to set the field that caused this issue as null (`field.set(instance, null)`), and i was able to print the entire object, and i was able to use the debugger ! So this means that it's an Unsafe thing that it does not even set fields' value to null, which is very anoying but, it's ok...

Now i think that my jvm crashed because as the debugger tried to introspect my allocated object, it received an NPE, even if it certainly check if the object was not null, thus, this made an internal error in the debugger, and then the JVM crashed.

EDIT: it seems like it's not just when memory is not initialised by Unsafe, "cursed null" fields looks to appear when Unsafe touches an object (putInt, putObject...). If an Unsafe method is invoked to put something in an object's memory, any null field of the object have a (high) chance to become a weird null field